# Python Pandas Linear Interpolate Y over X

Tags: python, pandas, linear-interpolation

I'm trying to answer this Udacity question:
https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-st101/l-48696651/e-48532778/m-48635592

I like Python & Pandas so I'm using Pandas (version 0.14)

I have this DataFrame `df=`

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(size=(1400,
                        2400,
                        1800,
                        1900,
                        1300,
                        1100), 
                   cost=(112000,
                         192000,
                         144000,
                         152000,
                         104000,
                         88000)))
```

I added this value of 2100 square foot to my data frame (notice there is no cost; that is the question; what would you expect to pay for a house of *2,100* sq ft)

```
 df.append(pd.DataFrame({'size':(2100,)}), True)
```

The question wants you to answer *what cost/price you expect to pay*, using linear interpolation.

**Can Pandas interpolate? And how?**

I tried this:

```
df.interpolate(method='linear')
```

But it gave me a cost of *88,000*; just the last cost value repeated

I tried this:

```
df.sort('size').interpolate(method='linear')
```

But it gave me a cost of *172,000*; just halfway between the costs of  *152,000* and *192,000*
Closer, but not what I want. The correct answer is *168,000* (because there is a "slope" of $80/sqft)

EDIT:

I checked these SO questions

- [Interpolation on DataFrame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10464738/1175496)

  - Demonstrates "1D" linear interpolation; that gives me the wrong answer
- [Pandas interpolate data with units](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19251766/1175496)

  - Demonstrates what I needed; "2D" linear interpolation; but this question is focused on the Python `quantities` library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas' `method='linear'` interpolation will do what I call "1D" interpolation

If you want to interpolate a "dependent" variable over an "independent" variable, make the "independent" variable; i.e. the Index of a Series, and use the `method='index'` (or `method='values'`, they're the same)

In other words:

```
pd.Series(index=df.size, data=df.cost.values) #Make size the independent variable
    # SEE ANSWER BELOW; order() method is deprecated; use sort_values() instead
    .order() #Orders by the index, which is size in sq ft; interpolation depends on order (see OP)
    .interpolate(method='index')[2100] #Interpolate using method 'index'
```

This returns the correct answer *168,000*

This is not clear to me from the example in [Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html), where the Series' `data` and `index` are the same list of values.

Answer (score 3):

with my version of Pandas (0.19.2) index=df.size breaks
unlucky choice of words -- things is size of the table ... so this works

```
df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'size':(2100,)}), True)
pd.Series(index=df['size'].values, 
data=df['cost'].values).order().interpolate(method='index')[2100]
```

=168000.0

Answer (score 2):

In my version of Pandas (1.1.1), `order()` is deprecated. you should use `sort_values()` instead. This does the job:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'size':(2100,)}), True) 
pd.Series(index=df['size'].values, 
data=df['size'].values).sort_values().interpolate(method='index')[2100]
```

=168000.0